# python. write to file, cannot understand behavior

Tags: python

I don't understand why I cannot write to file in my python program. I have list of strings `measurements`. I want just write them to file. Instead of all strings it writes only 1 string. I cannot understand why.
This is my piece of code:

```
fmeasur = open(fmeasur_name, 'w')
line1st = 'rev number, alg time\n'
fmeasur.write(line1st)
for i in xrange(len(measurements)):
    fmeasur.write(measurements[i])
    print measurements[i]
fmeasur.close()
```

I can see all print of these trings, but in the file there is only one. What could be the problem?

Comment: By `only one` do you mean all of them are in the same line without any newline? In such a case you have to append a newline with each write to the file

Comment: instead of using `xrange` to iterate throught `measurements` you should just use `for item in measurements` or if you need the index `for index,item in enumerate(measurements)`

Comment: How about you show us some of your other code, maybe the contents of measurements?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The only plausible explanation that I have is that you execute the above code multiple times, each time with a single entry in `measurements` (or at least the *last* time you execute the code, `len(measurements)` is `1`).

Since you're overwriting the file instead of appending to it, only the last set of measurements would be present in the file, but *all* of them would appear on the screen.

**edit** Or do you mean that the data is there, but there's no newlines between the measurements? The easiest way to fix that is by using `print >>fmeasur, measurements[i]` instead of `fmeasur.write(...)`.

Comment: What you probably want is the "write-append" mode, `a`, not the "write-overwrite" mode, `w`.